# How to pass value in variable in SAP HANA expression?

Tags: hana

Based on below formula, [Yesterday] variable is holding last date value but at run time it is not returning any result.

What should be the right syntax here?

```
=Sum([Total Amount])  Where ([Booking Date] = [Yesterday])
```

Answer (score 0):

Having all the code would be helpful, but with the info we have I would recommend removing the brackets and leaving the select like this:

```
where "BookingDate" = Yesterday;
```